# .htaccess redirect from non-www http subfolder to www https subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, subdirectory

I use this simple code to redirect non-www http to www https

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It succesfully redirect http://example.com to https://www.example.com.
But when I tried to access http://example.com/somefolder it did not redirected. Am I missing some syntax here? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Change %{REQUEST_URI} to /$1 ( first match in rule .* )

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

or modify last rule pattern:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```